# Error with wp_redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect admin users to a maintenance page (https://mysite/maintenance/), but firefox tells me the redirection is not correctly made

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirect' );
function custom_redirect()
{
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/maintenance/') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the template_include filter for this:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse_44239_template_include', 1, 1);
function wpse_44239_template_include($template){
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/maintenance/') );
        exit;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

`template_redirect` is the action called directly before headers are sent for the output of the rendered template. It's a convenient hook to do 404 redirects, etc... but shouldn't be used for including other templates paths as WordPress does this innately with the 'template_include' filter.

`template_include` and `single_template` hooks deal ONLY with the path of the template used for rendering the content. This is the proper place to adjust a template path.

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific error Firefox is reporting? Sounds like it could be an infinite redirect loop. I would suggest adding a check to make sure you're not already on the maintenance page, ie:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirect' );
function custom_redirect()
{
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) 
    {
         global $wp;
         $current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );
         $position = strpos( $current_url , '/maintenance/' );
         if ($position===FALSE) {
          wp_redirect( home_url('/maintenance/') );
          exit;
         }
    }
}
```